# Add free drawing result on another canvas in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

There are two canvas instance, the smaller 'd' for free drawing, the bigger 'c' is to be added on. How can I only add the boundary of drawing on 'd' to 'c', not the entire 'd' canvas area with lots of empty area to 'c'?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at3c0h31/1/)**

I hope the code can explains more clear. thanks.

**HTML**

```
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="c"></canvas>
<canvas width="150" height="150" id="d"></canvas>
<button id="btn">add To c</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c')
var d = new fabric.Canvas('d', {
    isDrawingMode: true
})

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = addDrawToBig

function addDrawToBig(){
  var svg = d.toSVG()
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg,function(objects, options) {
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    c.add(obj).centerObject(obj).setActiveObject(obj);
  });
}

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  stroke: 'red',
  radius: 15,
  left: 15,
  top: 15
})

d.add(circle)
d.renderAll()

addDrawToBig()
```

Comment: sorry i tried several times and still cannot post my question. i'm a beginner in stackoverflow. apologize.

Comment: no need to apologize, it's all good with your last update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i find the answer to my question, just use fabric.Group and .clone() method:

```
function addDrawToBig(){
  var group = [ ]
  d.getObjects().forEach(function(path){
    path.clone(function(copy){
      group.push(copy);
    });
  });
  group = new fabric.Group( group )
  c.add(group).centerObject(group).setActiveObject(group);
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/at3c0h31/4/)

Special thanks to @AndreaBogazzi, wish a good day!

Comment: i like to see people using fabricJs so much.

Answer (score 0):

i updated your fiddle with something that works better.
[[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at3c0h31/2/)](http://jsfiddle.net/at3c0h31/2/)

Canvas.toSVG() is not meant to be used as a export import function.

I suggest you to cycle throught the canvas objects and clone all of them in the new canvas.
This demo is not really cloning them, just copying them on the other canvas.
Without cloning you have the side effect that if you modify something in one canvas the modification get mirrored in the other.
You should add

```
c.add(ao[i].clone());
```

But for some reason free drawing path .clone() is failing. ( will look in this next days to see if it is a bug or a misusage )

```
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c')
var d = new fabric.Canvas('d', {
    isDrawingMode: true
})

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = addDrawToBig

function addDrawToBig(){
    var ao = d.getObjects();
    console.log(ao);
    for(var i in ao) {
      c.add(ao[i]);
    }
}

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    stroke: 'red',
    radius: 15,
    left: 15,
    top: 15
})

d.add(circle)
d.renderAll()

addDrawToBig()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @AndreaBogazzi, your fiddle seems to make each drawing/path added on 'c' individually, which is not exactly what I want. But thanks to your idea, i updated this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/at3c0h31/3/), and fabric.Group is the right method to rescue. Thanks so much!